# Trouble getting search results using MGTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I'm using a version of Matt Gemmell's MGTwitterEngine, and I'm trying to get some results from the getSearchResultsForQuery method.

```
// do a search
[_engine getSearchResultsForQuery:@"#quote"];

// delegate method for handling result
- (void)searchResultsReceived:(NSArray *)searchResults forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
{
    if ([searchResults count] > 0)
    {
        NSDictionary *singleResult = [searchResults objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *text = [singleResult valueForKey:@"text"]; 
        NSLog(@"Text at Index one: \n %@", text);
    }
}
```

However, I never appear to get the result. In the console, I get:

```
Request 7E4C3097-88D6-45F1-90D2-AD8205FBAAC5 failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=400 "Operation could not be completed. (HTTP error 400.)"
```

Is there a way around this? Am I implementing the delegate method right?
(Also, I had difficulty installing the YAJL stuff for the engine, and wonder if that has something to do with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build MGTwitterEngine with DEBUG constant equal to 1, take a look at what finalURL gives you. Post it here or confirm that it is correct with http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation

Answer (score 0):

I get this:

(gdb) po error->_userInfo
{
    body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<hash>\n
  <request>/oauth  /access_token\n
  <error>Client application is not permitted to use xAuth.</error>\n</hash>\n";
  response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1c88b0>;
}

You need to request xauth for your application.